# Android convert webview into PDF

Tags: java, android, pdf, webview

I am trying to convert webview in Android into pdf file. This is the function when my button is onClick:

```
public void export(WebView wv) {
    Context context = getApplication();
    String jobName = context.getString(R.string.app_name) + " Document";
    PrintAttributes attributes = new PrintAttributes.Builder()
            .setMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.ISO_A4)
            .setResolution(new PrintAttributes.Resolution("pdf", "pdf", 600, 600))
            .setMinMargins(PrintAttributes.Margins.NO_MARGINS).build();
    File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM + "/PDFTest/");
    PdfPrint pdfPrint = new PdfPrint(attributes);
    pdfPrint.print(wv.createPrintDocumentAdapter(jobName), path, "output_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".pdf");
}
```

And the PdfPrint class:

```
public class PdfPrint {

private static final String TAG = PdfPrint.class.getSimpleName();
private final PrintAttributes printAttributes;

public PdfPrint(PrintAttributes printAttributes) {
    this.printAttributes = printAttributes;
}

public void print(PrintDocumentAdapter printAdapter, final File path, final String fileName) {
    printAdapter.onLayout(null, printAttributes, null, new PrintDocumentAdapter.LayoutResultCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutFinished(PrintDocumentInfo info, boolean changed) {
            printAdapter.onWrite(new PageRange[]{PageRange.ALL_PAGES}, getOutputFile(path, fileName), new CancellationSignal(), new PrintDocumentAdapter.WriteResultCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onWriteFinished(PageRange[] pages) {
                    super.onWriteFinished(pages);
                }
            });
        }
    }, null);
}

private ParcelFileDescriptor getOutputFile(File path, String fileName) {
    if (!path.exists()) {
        path.mkdirs();
    }
    File file = new File(path, fileName);
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
        return ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_WRITE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to open ParcelFileDescriptor", e);
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

However, I am getting compile error message at `PrintDocumentAdapter.WriteResultCallback()`

The error message is

> WriteResultCallback is not public in
>   android.print.PrintDocumentAdapter.WriteResultCallback. Cannot be
>   accessed from outside package.

The problem is I am not able to locate android.print package. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try by creating a package inside your `src` folder with the name: `android.print`. Then create a file there with your "print" method.

**Alternatively**,

There is this lib [ConvertWebViewToPdfDemo](https://github.com/pramodkr123/ConvertWebViewToPdfDemo) which works very nice.

Usage sample:

```
        File directory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM + "/PDFTest/");
        final String fileName="Test.pdf";

        final ProgressDialog progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait");
        progressDialog.show();
        PdfView.createWebPrintJob(MainActivity.this, webView, directory, fileName, new PdfView.Callback() {

            @Override
            public void success(String path) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                PdfView.openPdfFile(MainActivity.this,getString(R.string.app_name),"Do you want to open the pdf file?"+fileName,path);
            }

            @Override
            public void failure() {
                progressDialog.dismiss();

            }
        });
```

Comment: As in move the print() in PdfPrint into the new file under android.print?

Comment: @hyperfkcb correct but I prefer to use lib I mentioned.  `ConvertWebViewToPdfDemo` is more reliable.

Comment: Sorry but what I meant was can I just move the PdfPrint class into android.print folder?

Comment: @hyperfkcb yes move your `PdfPrint.java` class there

Comment: Nope it does not work. The compile error message persist

Comment: Try with lib `ConvertWebViewToPdfDemo` I have used it without any issue

Comment: I am getting this error message when trying to compile the library: Failed to resolve: com.github.pramodkr123:ConvertWebViewToPdfDemo:1.0.4

Comment: Yeap yeap but I am having some trouble trying to get the Activity as I implemented the function in viewmodel

Comment: Do you have any ideas how to include the header and footer for every pages in pdf? What I did now was include the header and footer in webview then export the webview as pdf. However, when the page is more than one, the footer is only showing in the last page and header in the first page

Comment: @hyperfkcb no idea how to include header-footer for each pdf page

Comment: Also, I realized there is a problem with the progressDialog. It does not show at all. Do you have any ideas why is it so?

Comment: Can we add-footer on every page of PDF? (Footer must be from PDF not from web view). Will appreciate your help. :)